# How to play in any browser any video format for which codecs are installed in the system?

Tags: video, browser, codec, avi

I am developing a system, among the functions of which may be playing local video files of the user. User video files can be in any format. 
There is an idea to use browser as a GUI for this system (In this case, the core of the system will work as a web server). The system itself is very similar to a social network, so the idea with a browser is very logical.
Unfortunately, the standard VIDEO tag does not support any formats, even if the corresponding video codecs are installed on the user’s computer.

I need to understand: is there a way to get any browser to play any video? Since in any case there will be a client application, it is possible to install additional extensions for browsers, additional software etc. The main thing that it was a stable and working solution.

Answer (score 1):

“is there a way to get any browser to play any video?”

Yes and no. No, you can not install new codecs and have the browser use it. The browser will only ever use codecs it comes with.

You could compile a tool like ffmpeg to wasm, and do software decoding, then render to a canvas. However this is a big legal problem and you would need to obtain licenses for dozens of codecs. Or risk lawsuits

Comment: How about embed objects like flash or similar technology? Is this technologies already considered obsolete and not supported by browsers, or not?

Comment: Modern browsers do not support flash. And silver light has been dead for years.

Comment: Is it possible to write my extension through ActiveX / NPAPI / PPAPI? More precisely, it is unlikely that I will write it myself; Are there existing open source solutions? Or will these features also be removed from browsers? Or is the embedding of arbitrary objects unavailable, and in browsers there are lists of objects from well-known manufacturers, which are still allowed?

Comment: Search for NPAPI in Wikipedia, and look at the first sentence.